# How to render a different layout on registration error with devise in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, registration

I am using rails 3 with devise and i want to render a special ajax error layout when there are errors in the devise registration. How can i have the devise create registration action return an ajax layout i created when there are errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in case this helps anyone else. I found out that i can make a .js.erb files that match the devise files and on remote it calls them. This worked except for on the registration form for some reason. On that form i had to add this code to my layout_by_resource code block.

```
respond_to do |format|
  # format.js { "application" }
  format.js   { "../devise/registrations/new" }
  format.html { "application" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run:

```
  rails generate devise:views
```

Which will put all the devise views in your app/views directory.

From there you can edit the views to whatever you want(including your ajax response).

You may also need to edit the controllers, form there you can read:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Where they talk about configuring custom controllers.

Comment: I've read through everything i can find everywhere on the internet and for the life of me i can't get devise to respond with javascript using layout_by_resource.